# Passing state from child to child in react

Tags: react-native

I am just starting to learn coding so please bear with me. Could you help me solve the following problem?
I am trying to pass a state from one child component to another child component, I am using react-typist, once typing is done, I would like to change the style on my other component, which is my navigation bar. I believe I should lift the state up, but I cannot make it work.
Here is my code:

```
import Typist from 'react-typist';

class Intro extends Component {
      constructor (props) {
      super(props);
         this.state = {
         navStatus: 'back'
      };
      this.onIntroTyped=this.onIntroTyped.bind(this);
    }

    onIntroTyped(front){
    this.setState({ navStatus: 'front'});
    }

        render() {
        return (
          <Typist avgTypingDelay={10} 
          startDelay={0} 
          onTypingDone={this.onIntroTyped} 
          navStatus={this.state.navStatus}
          onIntroTyped={this.onIntroTyped}>
          <div class="text">
            .....
            </div>
          </Typist>
        );
      }
}

export default Intro;


class Nav extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: "slider",
            navStatus: "back"
        };      
    }

    onMenuClick = (event) => {
        if (this.state.id === "slider"){
            this.setState({id: "sliderOut"});
        }
        else (this.setState({id: "slider"}));
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <nav id="navigation" className={"navStatus"}>
            <div class="links">
            <a  href="#" onClick={this.onMenuClick}>Menu</a>
            ...
            </div>
            </nav>

        );
    }
}

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved state up to a wrapper parent component (Container component) called **Test** in this case.

The state **"navStatus"** is shared among its children's and the value is available to each children via props.

Also when a child want to change the value of that shared state it calls a method supplied by parent in this case it is `onIntroTyped`.
State of parent gets changed and all child elements gets rendered because of that and they have updated shared value via props.

Just for illustration purpose, see below example

```js
class Test extends React.Component {

   constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {
       navStatus: "back"
     };
     this.onIntroTyped=this.onIntroTyped.bind(this);
   }
  onIntroTyped(){
    this.setState({ navStatus: 'front'});
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( 
    <div>
          <Nav navStatus={this.state.navStatus} />
          <Intro onIntroTyped={this.onIntroTyped} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

class Intro extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
      }
    
    render() {
        return (
          <button onClick={this.props.onIntroTyped}> test Intro typed </button>
        );
      }
}

class Nav extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: "slider",
        };      
    }

    onMenuClick = (event) => {
        if (this.state.id === "slider"){
            this.setState({id: "sliderOut"});
        }
        else this.setState({id: "slider"});
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <nav id="navigation" className={this.props.navStatus}>
            <div class="links">
            <a  href="#" onClick={this.onMenuClick}>Menu</a>
            ...
            </div>
            </nav>

        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Test /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```